# Javascript file not showing up on browser

Tags: javascript

I'm using Visual Studio to practice javascript. When I save it and click Go Live to open it in a browser, nothing shows up after I select the file. Even though I saved it in a folder with and index file.

Heres the javascript file:

```
const penholder = {
  name: "Bamboo Blessing pen holder",
  penVolume: 10,
  colour: "bamboo",
  heightInches: 6,
  diameterInches: 3,
  currentPenCount: 2,
  penClickStatus: {
    whitePen: true,
    transparentPen: false,
  },
  clickPen: function (whiteClickStatus, transparentClickStatus) {
    this.penClickStatus.whitePen = whiteClickStatus;
    this.penClickStatus.transparentPen = transparentClickStatus;
  },
};

console.log("The backpack object: ", penholder);
```

and here's the index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Module demo</title>
    <script src="bambooPenHolder.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? And if you have any suggestions for how I should format my posts here, please let me know. I'm new here.

Comment: You have nothing in your `<body> `tags

Comment: How do you calling clickpen function from html?

Comment: Open the browser devtools to see the console. Use F12, Ctrl+Alt+J/K, or cmd+opt/alt+j/k